# Why is e2fsck just filling my screen with numbers?

Tags: hard-drive, 16.10, fsck

I ran e2fsck with an alternate superblock because my superblock was missing.  I couldn't actually boot ubuntu, so I ran this from recovery mode.

At the beginning it asked me if I wanted to narrow extent trees, and I pressed yes to all.

After a few minutes it started just printing numbers, the numbers scroll too fast to see and take up the whole screen. It's been going for about 20 or 30 mins (this is a 3TB NAS hard drive connected to SATAIII).

Should I stop it? How long should this be running for?